# ORA-00917 if passing SQL-Statement with escaped single quotes to OCIStmtExecute

Tags: c++, database, oracle, escaping

I succeed if I try to execute the following statement in Oracle SQL Developer. (Notice the last value of the first insert statement.)

```
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO attr_value
                (predef_class,
                 plan_nr,
                 key1,
                 key2,
                 key3,
                 key4,
                 key5,
                 type_id,
                 item_id,
                 access_type_id,
                 str_val)
    VALUES      (0,
                 0,
                 10000001,
                 1,
                 1,
                 1740,
                 0,
                 10242,
                 0,
                 10242,
                 'test''test');

    INSERT INTO attr_value
                (predef_class,
                 plan_nr,
                 key1,
                 key2,
                 key3,
                 key4,
                 key5,
                 type_id,
                 item_id,
                 access_type_id,
                 str_val)
    VALUES      (0,
                 0,
                 10000001,
                 1,
                 1,
                 1740,
                 0,
                 10248,
                 0,
                 10248,
                 '');

    INSERT INTO attr_value
                (predef_class,
                 plan_nr,
                 key1,
                 key2,
                 key3,
                 key4,
                 key5,
                 type_id,
                 item_id,
                 access_type_id,
                 dt_val)
    VALUES      (0,
                 0,
                 10000001,
                 1,
                 1,
                 1740,
                 0,
                 10237,
                 0,
                 10237,
                 '2000-01-01 00:00:00');

    INSERT INTO attr_value
                (predef_class,
                 plan_nr,
                 key1,
                 key2,
                 key3,
                 key4,
                 key5,
                 type_id,
                 item_id,
                 access_type_id,
                 float_val)
    VALUES      (0,
                 0,
                 10000001,
                 1,
                 1,
                 1740,
                 0,
                 10111,
                 0,
                 10111,
                 25.281797);

    INSERT INTO attr_value
                (predef_class,
                 plan_nr,
                 key1,
                 key2,
                 key3,
                 key4,
                 key5,
                 type_id,
                 item_id,
                 access_type_id,
                 in_val)
    VALUES      (0,
                 0,
                 10000001,
                 1,
                 1,
                 1740,
                 0,
                 10079,
                 0,
                 10079,
                 0);
END;
```

But the same statement fails with ORA-06550 'Statement ignored' and ORA-00917 'Missing comma' if I pass it to the OCIStmtExecute function defined in ociap.h.

Has anyone a hint for me how to overcome the problem?

Regards,
Ben

Comment: The best way to overcome quotation problems is to use prepared statement and pass values via bind variables.

Comment: As you can see in your first INSERT statement, You are using `test` string twice. Just try removing 1 of them.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai, it's my intent to pass a single quote in the 11th value. The value that I have chosen for my tests i.e. "test'test" may be stupid. But removing a part of it together with the single quote, which is the core of the problem, is no solution. In order to make it possible at all I doubled/escaped the single quote. But OCIStmtExecute refuses it although Oracle SQL Developer has no problem with it.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai As long as such errors *mostly* caused by typos, I think it is not a good idea to format source code: it is essential to post the code *as is* because exactly that code produces such behaviour. So consider reverting the edit if possible.

Comment: @BenA. Check the documentation on [text literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA): it allows not to use those doubled quotes which are especially painfull when you need to nest string literals into string literals and quote entire string with [`q'{text without closing curly bracket (}) followed by quote ('), because it is used as delimiter}'`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=587b87f2d5cf2f0c89dd375c9f693515). But the correct way is to use prepared statement

Comment: @astentx, I have only formatted the code to make it more readable. If there were any typos, They would still remain in the code since formatting never makes any changes in the code.

Comment: @astentx, my code has to serve both for Oracle and SQL Server. I haven't lernt so far that SQL Server supports the q' notation.